# Some way to prevent DDos/Dos attacking to Web Service on AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, ddos

I want to deploy my ASP.NET web service with EC2 on AWS. Is there any way to prevent  DDos attacking?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/340307/how-can-i-prevent-a-ddos-attack-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: Does AWS protect my webservice from DDos

Comment: @Nguyen - Nope. AWS EC2 provides infrastructure - VM. They do not provide DDOS prevention / mitigation services to EC2 instances.
However, they do have CDN services (Cloudfront) and even the option to host a static site at S3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several dedicated DDOS prevention services out there.
I would start with [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) + [Dome9](http://www.dome9.com/) combination - both services have a free tier.

Cloudflare will act as the public end point/ DDOS mitigation front-end, while Dome9 will make sure no one bypass Cloudflare for your 80/443 ports, and will keep your private administrative ports (RDP) stealth.